# What could be the purpose of this queue family?

Tags: vulkan

I have found this Android device: https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=20262#queuefamilies

[image]

The second queue family is a bit weird. It only supports present and sparse_binding. I'm not sure what could be a good use for it, doesn't even support transfer.

Comment: Ask the relevant party to update Vulkan guides, and not the general public. Speculation helps nobody.

Comment: @krOoze Sorry I don't understand your comment, what Vulkan guides are you talking about? Why do you say speculation helps nobody? Am I speculating? I already asked Samsung developer support, if I get an answer I will post it here.

Comment: You are asking us about capabilities of some proprietary driver. Who's responsibility it is to satisfactorily document it? StackOverflow randos (who can't know anyway, only guess), or the vendor? Speculation helps nobody because it is speculative, if not outright misinformation. Adreno is Qualcomm I think; Samsung is just integrator\reseller.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities.

It could be a dedicated queue for presentation and sparse binding. I'm not sure why you would need such a thing since the main queue family supports both of those *and* offers multiple queues. But it's there.

Alternatively, there could be some functionality that this queue family supports which is not checked by the website in question. You sometimes see these sorts of things in memory types, where an implementation [supports a bunch of memory types that appear to be identical](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=20237#memory). However, once you use the implementation, you find that you are guided to using those memory types because images with certain usage patterns (like render targets of specific kinds of formats) force you to use them.

In this case, there could be some extension functionality that this second queue supports that isn't available to the first queue.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked two engineers at Samsung. Still not 100% convinced with the replies but here's what they told me, in case anyone finds it useful.

---

### First engineer

First engineer wasn't sure about the purpose of that queue. However, it gave me some confidence that presentation is NOT the intended use for this queue.

There was a presentation at [Vulkanised 2023](https://vulkan.org/events/vulkanised-2023) called "Battle-tested optimisations for mobile by Ralph Potter, Samsung.". You can find the slides in the previous link. Unfortunately, the video of the presentation is not available (he told me that there was an issue with the recording of the event and he had to do the recording again).

In page 30 of the slides, there is the following advice: "Use a separate thread for your vkQueuePresent calls".

The reason for this is that when you call `vkQueuePresent` the Android compositor can block the thread for a significant amount of time (10ms as an example). During this time we could be doing useful work in the CPU.

However, he told me, that even though it's recommended to use a separate thread for present calls, there isn't a strong need for having a separate queue for working with this thread (although it might be useful in some rare cases), i.e. just using a mutex at `vkQueueSubmit` should be enough and it's what he recommended. So he told me that, most likely, presentation is not what this queue family was designed for.

---

### Second engineer

Second engineer told me that the purpose of this queue is *sparse resource management*. Apparently, sparse resource binding commands can be quite expensive ([documentation](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/site/spec/latest/chapters/sparsemem.html)), so it can be a good idea to have those command work in parallel, not to disrupt the execution of rendering commands for example.

I also asked him if there was any benefit for using this specific queue family, instead of the general purpose one. He couldn't give me an an answer for this one, and suggested me to ask Qualcomm (still waiting for an answer). My guess is that it could just be that having this extra queue allows you to allocate the general-purpose queues for other matters. After all, you only have 3 general-purpose queues and 1 specific-purpose queue. So you could, for example, use the 3 general-purpose queues for: 1) rendering+presentation, 2) compute, 3) async transfers.